# SOC embedded SRAM cache coherency

Tags: caching, memory, static, embedded, ram

I'm studying the topic of Memory Hierarchy in Embedded Systems. On some embedded SOC devices dedicated SRAM is provided on die. My question is:

Why is SOC embedded SRAM usually not cache coherent with the main memory system?

As a result usually SRAM is mapped to a non-cached address space.

I know that the contents of SRAM depend on the application and usually a specific linker section maps specific data structures to SRAM in order to decrease access time to those data.
For instance, it is possible to place the Interrupt Vector Table into SRAM decreasing access time and forcing deterministic interrupt handling. Caching SRAM would make SRAM access not deterministic because of the possibility of cache misses to take place.

Anyway I don't understand if this is related to the reason why SRAM is not cache coherent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On die memory us usually very fast.  Depending on how small/embedded you are asking about the cache and the on chip ram are the same speed so it would be silly to slow down the on die sram by adding extra cycles and widening the accesses by putting sram in front of it.  Those systems often have on chip flash as well and that does desire a cache or some sort of buffering to speed up execution and in that case you would see the cache in front of the flash.  To use the cache in front of sram for data accesses you would need some sort of memmory management, more stuff to take space on die and more stuff to slow things down.  A simple solution is to for example in the chip design declare everything with the msbit of the address set uncached and put your peripherals there and everything with the msbit not set cachable if the cache is enabled and put your ram and flash there.

If you have on chip and off chip memory that off chip memory space might want a cache and probably like the upper address bit or bits solution have only the off chip memory being cached (since it is likely slower).

In order to boot the vector table needs to be in flash, in general.  Some systems let you after boot switch what memory responds to that address space, branch to another address space for the flash, flip a control bit and now there is ram at the ivt, then you copy or create your new vector table in ram.  The flash memory that holds the ivt on boot is not necessarily non-deterministic, I would lean toward it being very deterministic, as deterministic as the on chip ram.  Perhaps a few clocks slower per access.  Your interrupt and any other execution performance is often more determined by your language and compiler than the system.

Perhaps you should specify the exact system or systems you are confused about.

Comment: So the reason is that SRAM and cache performances are very similar since they are built resorting to the same memory technology. That's why there is no need to have a cache between CPU and SRAM. Concerning the vector table I agree with you.

Comment: they will likely happen to be the same technology as it is the same chip, foundry and cell library.  The main reason though is they are local memories and can be one or a few clocks per transfer depending on cost, etc.  Without specifics though we can only talk about generalities which can vary.